# Rails showing failed conditional result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is my method in controller:

```
def destroy
    logger.info "INCOMING ATTACHMENT #{params[:id]}"
    @prod = ProductAttachment.find(params[:id])
    @product = Product.find(@prod.product_id)
    if params[:id] == @product.cover_id
      logger.info "ATTACHMENT MATCHED"
      @prod = ProductAttachment.where(:product_id => @prod.product_id)
      logger.info "ATTACHMENT #{@prod.count}"
    else
      logger.info "ATTACHMENT NOT MATCHED"

    end
    #@product_attachment.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to product_attachments_url, notice: 'Product attachment was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Even though my `params[:id]` is equal to `1156` and `@product.cover_id` return `1156` my conditional loop still print out `ATTACHMENT NOT MATCHED`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`params[:id]` is a string and `@product.cover_id` is an integer, you may change them both to string or integer for comparing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pitfall that I fell into too. I was expecting

```
params[:something] == true
```

but after carefully inspecting each elements in params with help of `binding.pry` I tried

```
params[:something].class
```

**And there it was. It printed out `string`.**

And suddenly I was enlightened. That being said, not only integer everything in params is string.